# Cómo utilizar el método authorize en el FormRequest Validation de Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, formrequest

Utilizo un Form Request como el siguiente:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use App\Product;

class ProductRequest extends FormRequest
{

  public function authorize(){
        if($this->user()->type == 'ADMIN'){
            return true;
        }else if($this->user()->type == 'USUARIO'){
            //return $this->user()->can('update', $this->nombre);  
        }else{
            return false;
        }
        
        
    }

public function rules(){

   return [
      'nombre' => ['max:50', 'nullable'],   
      'precio' => ['integer', 'min:0', 'nullable'],
      'marca' => ['max:20', 'nullable'],        
   ];
}
```

}

Mi pregunta es cómo puedo hacer que un usuario tipo "USUARIO" pueda editar el nombre y la marca por ejemplo, y el usuario tipo "ADMIN" pueda crear y editar todos los campos.
Tengo Laravel 8.1

Comment: En ese caso podrías dejar en el request solo los campos que puede editar el usuario limitado. No lo pondría en autorización porque no le devolvería al usuario un error mientras validen los campos que sí puede editar

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ pero como podría el usuario sin limitaciones editar los otros campos? no entiendo muy bien el funcionamiento del authorize, pero de todas formas en la vista también muestro mensajes de error si quisiera editar otros campos. Por el momento tengo estas validaciones de tipo-usuario en el controlador.

Comment: A lo que voy es que authorize es para autorizar o no la solicitud entera. Que para que el usuario tipo "USUARIO" pueda editar el nombre y la marca, lo manejes en otro método, como rules o validated

Comment: ahh ok entiendo, gracias @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: Luego en el controlador, recibes `$request->validated()` con sólo los campos correspondientes a cada tipo de usuario.